# Counting increasing and decreasing permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Given a number $N$, I want to count the number of permutations of $N$ such that there exists an $i$ for which

- $P_j<P_{j-1}$ for all $i\le j\le N-1$
- $P_j>P_{j+1}$ for all $2\le j\le i$

Where $P_i$ is the $i$th element in a permutation. For example, if $N = 3$ the valid permutations are $[1, 3, 2]$ and $[2, 3, 1]$.

So what it essentially asks you to do is, find an $i$ such that all elements before $i$ are less than the $i$th element, and all elements after $i$ are also less than the $i$th element.

So, my take is, for all valid permutations,  $P_i$ has to be the maximum element in the permutation, so there are $\binom{N-1}{i-1}$ ways to arrange $i-1$ numbers in ascending order, and just 1 way to arrange the rest of elements. So the answer should be
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\binom{N-1}{i-1}$$
But I've been told this is wrong, so I was wondering what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula seems correct to me; note that it is the same as:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{N-2}{{N-1}\choose{j}}$$

which in turn is:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}{{N-1}\choose{j}} - {{N-1}\choose{0}} - {{N-1}\choose{N-1}}$$

which equals $2^{N-1} - 1 - 1 = 2^{N-1} -2$.

Alternatively, there is a bijection $f$ between the permutations you are interested in and the proper, non-empty subsets of $[N-1]$ (place the elements of any such a subset to the left of $N$ in increasing order; and place the remaining elements from $[N-1]$ to the right of $N$ in decreasing order, to obtain a satisfactory permutation).

Therefore, there are $2^{N-1} - 2$ such permutations (i.e., the same of as the number of all subsets of $[N-1]$ except for $\emptyset$ and $[N-1]$).

Comment: How did you come up with $2^{N-1}$  ?

Comment: It's a handy thing to know; from the binomial theorem: $(1+x)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{i}}x^n$; and letting $x=1$ we get $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{i}} = 2^n$